# Inject Repository with BlocProvider in onGenerateRoute

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-navigation

I am trying to learn bloc for flutter and I came across a problem,

I am trying to make a weather app, based on [BLOC weather app](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterweathertutorial), but I want the routing to be done by onGenerateRoute, the problem is the method of the class has to be static, and the repository i am passing is a final field, initialized through the constructor of the class.

Code -

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:weather/bloc/weather_bloc.dart';
import 'package:weather/repositories/WeatherRepository.dart';
import 'package:weather/screens/errors/404.dart';
import 'package:weather/screens/loading/splashscreen.dart';

class WeatherRouter {
  final WeatherRepository weatherRepository;

  WeatherRouter(this.weatherRepository);
  
  static Route<dynamic> routes(RouteSettings settings) {
    //Uncomment below line as needed
    // final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SplashScreen());
        break;
      case 'weather':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => BlocProvider(
                create: (context) =>
                    WeatherBloc(weatherRepository: weatherRepository)));
        break;
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FourZeroFour());
    }
  }
}
```

Error -
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

why don't you remove the keyword `static`?

```dart
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:weather/bloc/weather_bloc.dart';
import 'package:weather/repositories/WeatherRepository.dart';
import 'package:weather/screens/errors/404.dart';
import 'package:weather/screens/loading/splashscreen.dart';

class WeatherRouter {
  final WeatherRepository weatherRepository;

  WeatherRouter(this.weatherRepository);
  
 Route<dynamic> routes(RouteSettings settings) { // <-- remove static from here!
    //Uncomment below line as needed
    // final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SplashScreen());
        break;
      case 'weather':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => BlocProvider(
                create: (context) =>
                    WeatherBloc(weatherRepository: weatherRepository)));
        break;
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FourZeroFour());
    }
  }
}
```

check [this](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/recipesflutterblocaccess?id=app-router) for reference on how to use flutter_bloc with routeGenerator ;)